# Can't start the podman service in colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, podman

is that possible to start podman in colab?
I had tried to follow the instructions as below, but failed to start the podman service? what should I do next? thanks
https://podman.io/getting-started/installation

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to their position on running virtualization inside a notebook.

[Running Docker on Google Colab](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/299#issuecomment-615308778)